# mandar valores de checkbox como arreglo mediante ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

hola tengo el siguiente problema.. necesito mandar los valores de un grupo de checkbox en un array, mediante ajax y procesarlos en php con codeigniter. estoy comenzando con ajax por lo que no se aun mucho del asunto, su aporte seria muy importante, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```html
<form id="formid">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="page[]" class="up">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="page[]" class="up">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="page[]" class="up">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="page[]" class="up">
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="page[]" class="up">
  <a href="#" id="enviar" />Enviar</a>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#enviar').click(function(){
        var selected = '';    
        $(":checkbox[name=page]").each(function(){
            if (this.checked) {
                selected += $(this).val()+', ';
            }
        }); 
        if (selected != '') 
            $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',
            data: selected,
            url: 'roles/paginas',
            success: function(data){
            alert('datos enviados');
            }
           }); 
        else
            alert('Debes seleccionar al menos una opción.');

        return false;
    });         
});    
</script>
```

como puedo mandar los valores en un array y procesarlos en mi controlador en php

Comment: Cris, usa ese tema para que te guíes. Envía los datos del formulario usando: `$('#formid').serialize()` Y obtenlos en tu controlador mediante `$this->input->post('page')`.

Comment: le voy a dar una mirada haber si puedo adaptarlo a lo que deseo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hay un error y otras cosas para mejorar en este código:

1. El error: Donde pones los checkbox, usa `name="page"` en lugar de `name="page[]"` pues sino no encuentra lo que estas intentando buscar.
2. Mejoras: Te conviene usar `json` para enviar los datos por ser un standard, es legible, ya hay formas robustas de generarlos y parsearlo, etc. Así que hice unos pequeños cambios que comente en el código para que puedas verlos.

El principal es usar `dataType: "json"` en la solicitud ajax ya que esto hace que se envie (y se reciba la respuesta, si la hay) estructurada y directo en forma de objetos sin tener que estar parseando manualmente.

El resto están comentadas en el código, como usar un Array en lugar de una cadena para armar el arreglo.

Salu2

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#enviar').click(function() {
    // defines un arreglo
    var selected = [];
    $(":checkbox[name=page]").each(function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        // agregas cada elemento.
        selected.push($(this).val());
      }
    });
    if (selected.length) {

      $.ajax({
        cache: false,
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json', // importante para que 
        data: selected, // jQuery convierta el array a JSON
        url: 'roles/paginas',
        success: function(data) {
          alert('datos enviados');
        }
      });

      // esto es solo para demostrar el json,
      // con fines didacticos
      alert(JSON.stringify(selected));

    } else
      alert('Debes seleccionar al menos una opción.');

    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="formid">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="page" class="up">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="page" class="up">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="page" class="up">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="page" class="up">
  <input type="checkbox" value="5" name="page" class="up">
  <a href="#" id="enviar" />Enviar</a>
</form>
```

Luego, para agarrar este arreglo en PHP necesitas hacer algo parecido a lo siguente:

```
// obtienes el cuerpo del POST
$entityBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

// decodificas el JSON
$data = json_decode($entityBody, true); // true es para recibir un array en $data

print_r($data); // ["1","2","3","4","5"] si estan todos seleccionados.
```

Comment: hola gracias por responder, reacomode mi codigo pero,  tengo el problema  que siempre me salta al else.. 'debe seleccionar una opcion..' cual podria ser el problema

Comment: @Criss ¿seguro que copiste todas las diferencias? fijate en este ejemplo, que si entra en el brazo verdadero del _if_

Comment: uff, fue culpa mia me habia olvidado del name en el input.. gracias, una consulta mas, mediante post como podria procesar ese arreglo en mi controlador php? gracias por la ayuda

Comment: @Criss ahora agrego el como cacharlo en php

Comment: muchas gracias, era lo que necesitava :)

Comment: como podria saber, si estoy obteniendo respuesta..  dentro del succes?, por que no pasa nada

Comment: @Criss si la respuesta al POST no esta en formato JSON no se invocara este método. Si quieres confirmar completamente, en el PHP puedes responder usando `json_encode` (busca la documentacion ahi hay ejemplos) y verifica la respuesta en el success.

Comment: gracias estoy leyendo y ya comprendo mejor, ya que soy nuevo en esto. y mi ultima pregunta seria.. despues de decodificar el JSON en php puedo recorrer en un foreach cada uno de sus valores? como haria esto

Comment: Una vez que lo decodificas, lo tienes en un array php, lo recorres como normalmente lo harias con un arreglo creado en php. Te recomiendo que si tienes una nueva pregunta que se desvia de la pregunta original, hagas una nueva pregunta en el sitio. Sino esta información como que se _pierde_ en los comentarios. Salu2.